# VBA( macros) copy and paste

Tags: vba, copy-paste

I am trying to create a macros that will allow me each time it's activated to copy the value of a  cell in worksheet 1 (the same cell but which would probably have differrent results after my calculation) and to paste the value of those results  in worksheet 2 (maybe in A1;A2;A3;....... each time I make a calcul) this is a sample of a code i have written but which isn'working:

```
Sub recorder()

If Cells(B, i) <> Empty Then
i = i + 1
Worksheets(1).Select
Cells(A1).Copy
Worksheets(2).Select
Cells(B, i) = Cells(A1)
End If
End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Paste this into ThisWorkbook.
Whatever you change the value in Cell A1 on Sheet1 it will appear on Sheet2 in the nearest blank cell in column A. Note you don't need to run a macro it happens automatically.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Sh.Index = 1 Then Exit Sub
If Not Target.Address = "$A$1" Then Exit Sub
If Worksheets(2).Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Value = Empty Then
Worksheets(2).Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Value = Target.Value
Else
Worksheets(2).Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Target.Value
End If    
End Sub
```

Comment: but if "A1" is result cell ie A1= B1+C1 the code won't register the result in sheet 2 why's that?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
Sub recorder()

    Sheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value

End Sub
```